# Trying to figure out a way to get a redstone signal from an empty hopper minecart

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Essentially, I want a hopper minecart to stop moving once it's empty. I have a straight line of rail, with a block at each end, and rails all along it such that the minecart bounces back and forth between the ends. My current plan of attack is to have the powered state of the powered rail at one of the ends change based on the output of a detector+comparator+signal inverter, like so: [image]

The issue I run into is that the comparator+signal inverter has no way to differentiate between an empty minecart and no minecart at all: both result in it outputting nothing. I tried some sort of weird observer+detector rail thing a few blocks before the comparator detector, and then added an extra piston circuit such that the output of the comparator would only be considered when the minecart was over it, but couldn't get the timings to line up. It looked like this: [image: 2]]

I'm all out of ideas, any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just attach a regular redstone wire to the detector rail?

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot in the moment that detector rails put out a redstone signal for whatever reason... lol. Regardless, replacing the observer with a normal wire doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Looks like that piston won't do anything useful. It just temporarily disables something, as it's not a flip-flop.

Comment: Also, detector rails will power nearby powered rails - using detector rails that close to the end won't work.

Comment: [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/161965/1351) is definitely related, although I'd have to take a closer look to see if yours is a duplicate of it.  Have a look at the answers there to see if anything helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [moving minecart once hopper has items, and then becomes empty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161965/moving-minecart-once-hopper-has-items-and-then-becomes-empty) You should just be able to invert the input to have it stop moving instead of start moving when empty.